# "I don't after the position" or "I am not after the position"

Tags: word-choice, auxiliary-verbs

Is this sentence correct?

> I **don't** after the position.

I think that this is the correct sentence:

> I **am not** after the position.

Please let me know why the first sentence is wrong.

Comment: Your first example isn't valid because ***do*** there is just an auxiliary verb which requires a main verb (such as ***lust***, which would fit in your context). The second one is fine because ***am*** (=BE) is a copula form, which doesn't need another verb.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Would you consider posting your answer as an answer instead of putting it in the comments section?

Comment: @snailplane: I was kinda hoping someone else might be able to shed light on *why* a learner might confuse ***do*** and ***be*** in contexts like this (I like ELL answers that explain why people might be led into mistakes, as well as setting them straight about correct / idiomatic usage). I thought OP's misunderstanding here might be something to do with the way some Americans say *What **do** you got?* instead of *What **have** you got?* (imho, inadequately explained by saying that contracted *What'd'ya got?* would be the same for either). But basically yes - I'll get around to "answering".

Comment: @Jaj I'm guessing. Does *I'm not after something* sound like an action and so *after* sounds more like a verb in your first language? If that's the case, you can solve this kind of problem yourself the next time you find a similar expression (e.g., *He's ahead of his time*) by looking it up in dictionaries. If it (i.e., *after*, *ahead*, etc.) is a preposition, you need the verb *(to) be* (i.e., *am/is/are/was/were/has been/have been/had been*), not the verb *(to) do*.

Answer (score 1):

When you say *do not X*, X has to be a verb, not a preposition.

> I do not the candy (wrong)
>
> I do not want the candy (right)

It's wrong because *do + verb* is a construction often used in English, and if there is a *not*, it goes in the middle like other helping verbs, e.g. *I have not gone*, etc.

As an FYI, *go* works fine like this.

> I go after the candy.

but remember negative verb forms in English require *do*:

> I do not go after the candy.

Answer (score 0):

Examine the positive forms:-

"don't after" suggests the negation of a verb, since the English negation of the simple present tense uses "don't" followed by the bare infinitive.

- I after the position
- I am after the position.

Now the word "[after](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/after?s=t)" is a preposition, sometimes an adverb, or more rarely an adjective or a conjunction. It is not used as a verb. Hence "I don't after..." is not grammatically correct.

The second form is fine. The word "after" functions as a preposition, meaning "in pursuit of". And the English negation of "I am" is "I am not".